# Is it possible to add mutiple headers with same key to NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest

Is it possible to add mutiple headers with same key to NSMutableURLRequest?

I just come to a request that multiple headers with same key should be present in the headers, as I know , the NSMutableURLRequest's setHTTPHeaderField would only set some field, but not able to add duplicated item into the headers, is there anyway to achieve this? thanks.

Comment: i dont think a duplicate headers are accepted in NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: According to RFC2616, Chapter 4.3. at the end, multiple header fields with the same name (key) are only allowed, if the corresponding value is a list and the multiple values for that name have the same semantic, if it would be sent in a single header field with a list of comma-separated values. `a: 1`, `a: 2` is only allowed, if it has the same semantics as `a: 1, 2`. Therefore just replace it with a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `-setHTTPHeaderField` method, you likely mean `-setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`. This method always replaces an existing value. But you can do it. First of all, you have to know, that multiple header fields with the same name are only allowed under some circumstances:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
> present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].
> It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
> "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
> message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
> separated by a comma.

[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-32), 4.2

So, `a: 1`, `a: 2` has to have the equivalent `a: 1, 2`. This is, what
`-addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` does:

> This method provides the ability to add values to header fields incrementally. If a value was previously set for the specified field, the supplied value is appended to the existing value using the appropriate field delimiter. In the case of HTTP, the delimiter is a comma.

So you can do:

```
[request addValue:@1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"a"];
[request addValue:@2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"a"];
```

Comment: thanks, yes, I tried to use addValue:forHTTPHeaderField, it will combine the values into a comma connected group string. Like:   header:value1,value2.   My original thought is like header:value1  header:value2,  as I saw this in the document I got. It seems, there is no way to make it to act like that?

Comment: As cited from the RFC, this *should* not make any difference. Otherwise your web service is broken.

Comment: OK, yes, there is no difference, and we are aware of this limitation of the NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: Since both "formats" are equivalent, this is no limitation.